# singular_name label in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I was looking to get more info about 'singular_name' label and came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860227/what-is-the-difference-between-name-vs-singular-name-in-wordpress). Based on that link 'singular_name' value should show up when I click 'Add New' and 'Add New Post' window appears. My understanding the value would replace the 'Post' part in the 'Add New Post' title. It's not working for me.

My code

```
function portfolio_register() {

      $labels = array (
        'name' => __('Portfolio'),
        'singular_name' => __('Project'),
      ); 

      $args = array(

            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui'=> true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail') 
          );

          register_post_type('portfolio', $args);

    }

    add_action ('init', 'portfolio_register');
```

I was able to achive the desired effect using 'add_new' and 'add_new_item' labels, however, was just curious what is the purpose of 'singular_name' label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer at that link is incorrect.

The "Edit Animals" text from their answer uses the `edit_item` label, not `singular_name`. There's a much longer list of labels that you'll need to provide when registering a post type than just those two. The full list is kept [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/#description).

As for `singular_name`, as far as I can tell, this is only used to label menu items and link suggestions:

[image: menu item labels] [image: link suggestions]

In both those examples "Page" is where the `singular_name` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jacob. Your attached screenshot what is it taken from? Is there more info I can get to fully understand the purpose of singular_name or singular_label ? May be some examples of usage? I am not sure if I need singular_label in my code now..

Comment: The menus editor and the links tool in the classic editor. You should provide all the labels in your code. There's no reason not to. I don't know why your take-away from this would be that you don't "need" it.

Comment: Because based on this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/  $args is an optional parameter. that's the reason I am a bit confused. I am also not sure if I understand  how singular_label works as I was not able to find any clear explanation with some examples

Comment: It's "optional" only in the pure PHP sense that not providing it won't cause a crash. If you register a post type without args the defaults will all be used. The default post type is not "Portfolio", so you need to provide all the labels with the correct names.

Comment: Thank you for clarification Jacob. I will update my code as per your suggestions.

Comment: I just notices that by adding 'singular_name' => __('Project') to the list of labels it added 'Project' to the dropdown list of options in the upper admin bar - on the left there's a plus sign with dropdown 'Post' 'Page' 'Media' and now it has 'Project' added